# Validate dynamically created fields when one is changed

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a program that dynamically creates various text boxes / drop down lists.  I am trying to figure out how to validate these fields only when one is changed.  Basically if someone entered a date in the text box then I need the program to validate that the drop down list was changed or vice versa.  If there are no changes to both fields then it should not validate.  Any help would be extremely appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ValidatedDate" SortExpression="ValidatedDate">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValDate" Width="100px" MaxLength="10" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
            Text='<%# Bind("ValidatedDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="g1" ID="RegularExpressionValidator10"
            runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtValDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Validated Date: ##/##/####"
            ValidationExpression="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblValidatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ValidatedDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductStatus" SortExpression="ProductStatusDescription">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" AutoPostBack="true"
            DataTextField="StatusDescription" DataValueField="StatusID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProductStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductStatusDescription")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My apologies, the code can be a bit confusing without the correct context.

Comment: Are you generating some of this in a code-behind?  Because this just looks like *.ascx fragments.  If you're adding controls in code-behind, 1) Please show us the generation code.  2) Be sure to do it in `Page_Init()` not `Page_OnLoad()` or events won't get bound.

Comment: There is code-behind for this however it deals with the gridview(paging/sorting) that this information is put into.  This is from an *aspx page.  I would show more code but then it gets into sensitive material.  I am just at my wits end on this.  Everything works perfectly except for this one thing.

Comment: Are the events firing on dynamic controls: never? only when directly modified? not being fired because you didn't attach events to them?  If "never", see my original comment, be sure you're not changing the page structure later than you're supposed to...  PS - If it's worth being "sensitive" it should be worth writing a simple self-contained example that exhibits the problem from start to finish.

Comment: My apologies for not explaining this well, I would make a crappy teacher however thank you for your patience.  Part of this program displays information in gridview.  The user has the option to edit certain aspects of it.  There is an update link that updates a database once a change is made.  So, someone goes in there and makes changes and once they click the update button is when the validation needs to fire.  This is all executed only when directly modified.

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="ValidateEverything_Clicked"/>` then things like `string strToValidate = this.txtValDate.Text;` and `this.txtValDate.Text = validatedDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");` to get the job done.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

ebyrob, thank you for your help.  I figured it out however and it works beautifully.  Here is the code that fixed it all:

```
    protected void AddError(string errorMessage)
    {
        cstValidate.IsValid = false;
        cstValidate.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        cstValidate.EnableClientScript = false;
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtValidatedDate = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtValDate") as TextBox;
        DropDownList ddlStatusCompare = GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dropdownlist4") as DropDownList;
        if (txtValidatedDate.Text == string.Empty && ddlStatusCompare.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            AddError("Please enter a Validated Date");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else if (txtValidatedDate.Text != string.Empty && ddlStatusCompare.SelectedValue == "0" 
            || txtValidatedDate.Text != string.Empty && ddlStatusCompare.SelectedValue == "99")
        {
            AddError("Please remove the Validated Date");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        if (!e.Cancel)
            Helpers.LogChanges(GridView2, e, _employeeID, "SaleProducts");
    }
```